# Can you pull people out of their cars without getting in?

Tags: watch-dogs

In Watch Dogs, when approaching a car, there is a command to enter the vehicle by pressing triangle. Then the protagonist pulls out the driver and gets into the car himself.

I have recently been invaded, spotted the hacker hiding in a car and wanted to pull him out before his engine started, which worked, but then I started driving myself and the invader had enough time to get into another vehicle.

Is there a way to pull out the driver but not enter the vehicle yourself?

Comment: To the person, who voted to close: The game is released in two days and pre-orders are usually sent out earlier. I don't see any use in closing my question, just to open it again in two days.

Comment: If it *does* decide to get closed, the plan will be to delete it, not reopen it.

Comment: About the question: It's not Watch Dogs, but this works in GTA: Press The hijack button (in your case, triangle) and pull the analog stick away from the car while Aidan is pulling the driver out of his car. If done correctly (and if supported by the game), Aidan will start walking away from the car after he's pulled his victim out.

Comment: There's ~100 streamers on twitch for watch dogs right now.  Clearly the game is "available".

Comment: The game was "accidentally" made available early by some retailers.  However, it is not "generally available to the public," which is our criteria for whether or not a question about beta/unreleased games should be allowed.  Thus this question should be closed.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft I'm not sure how punishing those lucky enough to get a legit copy really fits into our policy.  We've allowed questions about games prior to release date before, as long as it seems to be a question asked in good faith, which this does.

Comment: I've asked a meta question for this, since it has now 4 close votes: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8655/should-questions-only-a-few-days-from-official-release-be-closed-for-unreleased

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to stop yourself from getting in the car when stealing it from a civilian. I can't 100% confirm that it is the case with online players, but I would assume that they are treated same way as civilians.

Comment: Unless you want to count the "rescue" action this answer is indeed correct.  `Rescue` is offered during a fire fight.

Comment: As far as I know, you can't *rescue* players, nor do you have control when you get the rescue prompt. It is a valid point for civilians though.

Comment: Actually it's pretty easy to control the rescue prompt take covered behind a car with a NPC in it.